# Angular v6 Elements @Input() For Initial Binding Not Working

Tags: angular6

I have created a custom element and placed on a page like this:

```
<my-custom-element [value]="100"></my-custom-element>
```

In the component definition, I have this:

```
@Input() value: number = 50;
```

At run-time, the value is always 50.  I expect it to be 100.  If I remove the default, value is undefined. What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: This code seems correct, it is difficult to know what's happening without the rest of it. Have you tried to restart npm?

Comment: After restart the element exhibits the same behavior.  What else would you like to see in the code?

Comment: I removed the brackets ... um ... it is working.  I could have sworn I tried that already.  Now, why do all of the examples I have ever seen have the brackets?  Confused.

Comment: i'm trying to reproduce your problem but i can't. are you sure you are printing your value and you are not looking at the beginning automated logging that prints initial value?

Comment: I threw the value into a console.log within the ngOnInit method. Once i removed the square brackets, things started working.  I probably did something else (because that does not make sense to me), however, I am not certain what I may have done other than that to correct the problem.  It would still be good to know whether my syntax is valid or not.

Comment: check this answer, it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955565/2721138

Comment: @cozmik05 The answer you referenced in that link is giving incorrect advice. You don't need to make the input property all lowercase. You can keep it camel-case, but when you use it as an angular element, then you need to separate the words by a dash character and make sure everything is lowercase.

Comment: @BillCunnien have you gotten this question answered or do you still need an answer? I have one if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

In NG Elements you may not find in your OnIt but in OnChanges.

Please add below line and check it is defined.

```
public ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log('on changes value: ', this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set data using `HTML attributes` and to change/update data in `Angular Elements` you have to use vanilla js, `query selector` and assign data like below

custom element tag with initial `value = 0`

```
<my-custom-element value="0" ></my-custom-element>
```

select custom element through the query selector and assign value.

```
var customElement = document.querySelector('my-custom-element');
customElement.value = 100;
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. You can pass arguments the HTML attributes way in angular elements

Comment: @KavindaJayakody, if you pass in using ElementRef or HtmlElement or whatever, then the attributes have to be added/modified in ngAfterViewInit of the component. If your element needs that input on ngOnInit, then this won't work.

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai yeah right. But what I mentioned was, we don't actually need to do it the way this answer suggests, we can actually use html attributes for the problem. The way it should be

Comment: Kavinda Jayakody and @KeyvanSadralodabai this scenario is for changing data on runtime.

Comment: @KavindaJayakody, I think html attributes don't work with angular elements the same way they do with regular DOM elements. I haven't been successful in wrapping attributes in brackets ([ and ]) for angular elements. The input property attributes of angular elements have to be literal values, or if you need dynamic variables to use as values, then you need to inject the Renderer2, get an ElementRef and use the Renderer2 to add attributes/events, etc. Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: @SunilKashyap I disagree. This is not for changing data on runtime, it's for assigning data period. His `value` is always 50 because the `[value]` is never being assigned for it to change. Let me know if you need clarification please.