# Angular web component @Input with variable

Tags: angular, angular-elements

https://angular.io/guide/elements

Before asking i try to find solution by myself but i can't solve my issue.
I have a web component (for example `<test-component></test-component>`)
And for initialization i need pass to it some param (for example `some-string-url`).
When i try to do it like that `<test-component some-string-url="https://example.com"></test-component>` everything works fine, but that param should be dynamic for each website or appliaction, so when i try to do that like that:
`<test-component [some-string-url]="someVariable"></test-component>` or
`<test-component some-string-url="{{ someVariable }}"></test-component>` it doesn't work. The only way what i found it's create component and append it to the div like that:

```
  const widget = document.createElement('test-component');
  widget.setAttribute('some-string-url', this.exampleUrl);
  document.getElementById('widget-container').append(widget);
```

but is there i can use another way to pass param?

P.S. ngOnChanges() didn't see any changes and don't triggered at all.

UPDATE:__________________________________________

I need to get @Input property from variable inside my web component (https://angular.io/guide/elements), for example `<test-component [some-string-url]="someVariable"></test-component>` should get me `some-string-url` inside my web-component.

Currently i've got `undefined` when i try to get `some-string-url` inside onInit, afterviewchecked.

Similar question but without solution [Angular Elements: @Input decorator not working with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540889/angular-elements-input-decorator-not-working-with-variables)

Comment: Share source of `test-component`.

Comment: `it doesn't work` can you specify ? What did you expect / What happened ? What you write should work. The common problem comes when you try to use this variable "too soon", before it has been passed to the component. Please show the code.

Comment: can you please share the code of your web component.

Comment: For values set with `@Input`, I recommend to use the setter form because you don't know *when* the value is filled and `ngOnInit` is too soon. The safest is to do it like this : `@Input set someStringUrl(value: string) { [...] }`. Also, the setter is called each time the value is changed, which can sometimes be useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it isn't working for you, both of those binding formats should work.

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66800193?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

**test.component.ts**

```js
export class TestComponent {

  @Input() someStringUrl: string;

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<test-component [someStringUrl]="someVariable"></test-component>

<button (click)="increaseCounter()">Increase Counter</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  private counter = 1;

  get someVariable() { 
    return `http://www.fake-address.com/${this.counter}`; 
  }

  increaseCounter() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not angular web component, i mean https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: This is just a normal Angular component, not a Web Component which was asked for